# find all Carmichael numbers in a given interval [a,b) - C

Tags: c, math, number-theory

I am working in a math software with different features one of them to be to find all Carmichael numbers in a given interval [a,b)

This is my code, but I don't know if I have done it correctly or not cause I can't test it since the smallest Carmichael number is 560 which is too big for my pc to process.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  unsigned int begin, end;

  printf("Write an int (begin):\n");
  scanf("%d", &begin);

  printf("Write an int (end):\n");
  scanf("%d", &end);

  int i;

  for( int i=begin; i<end; i++ ) {

    long unsigned int a_nr = i-1;

    int a[a_nr];

    for( int j=0; j<a_nr; j++ ) {
      a[j] = j;
    }

    unsigned long c_nr[a_nr];

    for( int k=0; k<a_nr; k++ ) {
      unsigned long current_c_nr;
      int mod;
      for( int l=0; l<i; l++ ) {
        current_c_nr= current_c_nr * a[k];
      }
      mod = current_c_nr%i;
      if( mod==a[k] && mod!=a[k] ) {
        c_nr[k] = i;
      }

    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

If it is not correct, where is the mistake?

Thank you

P.S Overflow should be prevented.

Comment: You need to initialize `current_c_nr` variable, as it's containing some garbage value after declaration

Comment: @SamProtsenko initialize with which value? 1?

Comment: I wouldn't know :) Depends on your algorithm implementation. I just noticed that you are using uninitialized variable in calculations, which could lead to erroneous result. But from logical point of view -- yes, it seems like it should be `1`.

Comment: You should implement a gcd function and an efficient modular exponentiation function (one that *doesn't* use repeated multiplication but instead uses exponentiation by squaring and that furthermore never involves intermediate numbers much bigger than the modulus) before you go searching for Carmichael numbers. Such functions are only a few lines of code and would enable you to verify 560 as a Carcmichael number in a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you say "This is my code, but I don't know if I have done it correctly or not cause I can't test it since the smallest Carmichael number is 560 which is too big for my pc to process" then the conclusion is -- you haven't done it correctly. You should be able to process 561 (560 must be a typo) in a small fraction of a second. Even if your algorithm is in principle correct, if it can't handle the smallest Carmichael number then it is useless.

`n` is Carmichael if and only if it is composite and, for all `a` with `1 < a < n` which are relatively prime to `n`, the congruence `a^(n-1) = 1 (mod n)` holds. To use this definition directly, you need:

1) An efficient way to test if `a` and `n` are relatively prime

2) An efficient way to compute `a^(n-1) (mod n)`

For the first -- use the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for greatest common divisors. It is most efficiently computed in a loop, but can also be defined via the simple recurrence `gcd(a,b) = gcd(b,a%b)` with basis `gcd(a,0) = a`. In C this is just:

```
unsigned int gcd(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
    return b == 0? a : gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

For the second point -- almost the worst possible thing you can do when computing `a^k (mod n)` is to first compute `a^k` via repeated multiplication and to then mod the result by `n`. Instead -- use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), taking the remainder (mod `n`) at intermediate stages. It is a divide-and-conquer algorithm based on the observation that e.g. `a^10 = (a^5)^2` and `a^11 = (a^5)^2 * a`. A simple C implementation is:

```
unsigned int modexp(unsigned int a, unsigned int p, unsigned int n){
    unsigned long long b;
    switch(p){
        case 0:
            return 1;
        case 1:
            return a%n;
        default:
            b = modexp(a,p/2,n);
            b = (b*b) % n;
            if(p%2 == 1) b = (b*a) % n;
            return b;
        }
}
```

Note the use of `unsigned long long` to guard against overflow in the calculation of `b*b`.

To test if `n` is Carmichael, you might as well first test if `n` is even and return `0` in that case. Otherwise, step through numbers, `a`, in the range `2` to `n-1`. First check if `gcd(a,n) == 1` Note that if `n` is composite then you must have at least one `a` before you reach the square root of `n` with `gcd(a,n) > 1`). Keep a Boolean flag which keeps track of whether or not such an `a` has been encountered and if you exceed the square root without finding such an `a`, return `0`. For those `a` with `gcd(a,n) == 1`, compute the modular exponentiation `a^(n-1) (mod n)`. If this is ever different from 1, return `0`. If your loop finishes checking all `a` below `n` without returning `0`, then the number is Carmichael, so return 1. An implementation is:

```
int is_carmichael(unsigned int n){
    int a,s;
    int factor_found = 0;
    if (n%2 == 0) return 0;
    //else:
    s = sqrt(n);
    a = 2;
    while(a < n){
        if(a > s && !factor_found){
            return 0;
        }
        if(gcd(a,n) > 1){
            factor_found = 1;
        }
        else{
            if(modexp(a,n-1,n) != 1){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        a++;
    }
    return 1; //anything that survives to here is a carmichael
}
```

A simple driver program:

```
int main(void){
    unsigned int n;
    for(n = 2; n < 100000; n ++){
    if(is_carmichael(n)) printf("%u\n",n);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

output:

```
C:\Programs>gcc carmichael.c

C:\Programs>a
561
1105
1729
2465
2821
6601
8911
10585
15841
29341
41041
46657
52633
62745
63973
75361
```

This only takes about 2 seconds to run and matches the initial part of [this](https://oeis.org/A002997) list.

This is probably a somewhat practical method for checking if numbers up to a million or so are Carmichael numbers. For larger numbers, you should probably get yourself a good factoring algorithm and use Korseldt's criterion as described in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) on Carmichael numbers.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!